# Emacs desktop doesn't remember TRAMP connections?

Tags: emacs

I use emacs to edit scripts and code files on several different servers.  TRAMP is working very well.  However, when I exit emacs, all my tramp connections go away.  I tried desktop-save-mode, but only local files show up when I restart emacs.  Is there some package that will remember tramp connections?  Is this just a configuration issue?

Comment: Have you tried emacs-server?
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html

Comment: Yes.  From what I understand, it requires that I actually shell into remote the machine and run emacsclient from there.  Good idea in some cases, but TRAMP is better for my needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can customize the variable `desktop-buffers-not-to-save` to do this:

```
(setq desktop-buffers-not-to-save "^$")
```

By default it is set to a regexp that matches TRAMP filenames.  I would have expected setting it to `nil` would have worked, but, alas, it does not.

Comment: You can set it to `^$`, IIRC.

Comment: Yes!  That was totally to cause.  I can kind of see why this is the default because loading tramp files is slow.

Comment: @User1 There are other desktop-like packages that deal with the delayed loading.  I thought there was even an addition to desktop itself which did the lazy loading.  Many are listed here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement

Comment: The "Sep 10 '16 at 11:47" edit of this answer by @DomQ changed the variable to change from `desktop-files-not-to-save` to `desktop-buffers-not-to-save`.  However, for me in Emacs 25.2.1 I do have to set `desktop-files-not-to-save` (not `desktop-buffers-not-to-save`) in order to preserve TRAMP files.

Comment: This is not fully tested, but I believe that the solution posted above does not work on my MacBook.  However it did work when I added the command mentioned in the comment above.  Consider change solution to the following?
```(setq desktop-buffers-not-to-save "^$")
(setq desktop-files-not-to-save "^$")``` (two separate lines)

Comment: I added exactly this to my init.el, and it has no effect. TRAMP buffers using ssh are never saved, while all local buffers are always saved.