# emacsclient to access remote emacs server

Tags: networking, emacs, ssh

I'm trying to open an emacsclient session from a remote host. I walked through the following steps on the [tramp website](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Frequently-Asked-Questions) How can I use TRAMP to connect to a remote Emacs session?.

I'll walk you through the step

1. on the remote host put in .emacs file

   ```
   (require 'server)
   (setq server-host "<IP ADDRESS of remoteHost>"
         server-use-tcp t)
   (server-start)
   ```
2. start emacs session on remote host
3. copy the ~/emacs.d/server/server from remoteHost to localHost keep the same path. (localHost:~/emacs.d/server/server)
4. on local host emacs shell

   emacsclient  /ssh:test@remoteHost:/tmp/test.py

But got the following error on my localHost

```
;; emacsclient: can't find socket; have you started the server?
;; To start the server in Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
;; emacsclient: connected to remote socket at `Remotehost`
;; emacsclient: connect: No route to host
;; emacsclient: No socket or alternate editor.  Please use:

    ;; --socket-name
    ;; --server-file      (or environment variable EMACS_SERVER_FILE)
    ;; --alternate-editor (or environment variable ALTERNATE_EDITOR)
```

So it seems to connect to remoteHost but cannot find a route. Similar questions have been ask on SO.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231902/originate-edit-of-remote-file-using-emacs-tramp-from-ssh-session) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978424/replacing-sshscreeneditor-with-emacs). There are also some nice code about copying directly the ~/.emacs.d/server/server from remoteHost to localHost [here](http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/06/25/emacsclient-and-tramp/).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/371/8563