# Session manager for emacs (with high ssh usage)

Tags: ssh, emacs, dot-emacs, tramp

I'm interested in using a session manager in emacs with the possibility of saving sessions by name.

The problem is that I almost exclusively use emacs to edit remote files. For this, I use tramp, which also works perfectly.

I want to have my sessions saved, including remote files and term buffers.

Does anyone know of a good way of saving sessions? I don't really care about windows sizes or splits

**I have tried the following, which does not work:**

Followed the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847962/what-alternate-session-managers-are-available-for-emacs/849180) post, and tried out desktop.el. Searching and saving by name works perfectly.

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4053708/emacs-desktop-doesnt-remember-tramp-connections) post recommends, I added this line so tramps are saved too:

```
(setq desktop-buffers-not-to-save "^$")
```

But, as I said, this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now it works. I'll post what I did, but I don't really know which was the problem.

Apparently, the line

```
(setq desktop-buffers-not-to-save "^$")
```

was not working. So I enter the customization interactively (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-gruop` <kbd>RET</kbd> `desktop` <kbd>RET</kbd>, changed the value of `Desktop Buffers Not To Save` to none, reload `.emacs`, and it worked.

Comment: I am also having this issue, but this solution did not resolve it for me.